# The meaning of "files dispertion" in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, upload

In the `Magento\Framework\File\Uploader`, there is a variable name `$_enableFilesDispersion`:

```
/**
 * If this variable is set to TRUE, files dispertion will be supported.
 *
 * @var bool
 * @access protected
 */
protected $_enableFilesDispersion = false;
```

My mother tongue is not English, so I do not understand the "**files dispertion**", what's the meaning of "**files dispertion**"?

If I set `$_enableFilesDispersion = true;`, what will happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you set `$_enableFilesDispersion = false;`  it will simply upload the file to the directory, but if you set it to `true` code will create subfolders with the image name's first two letters and then store the image there.

for eg. - an image having the name `abc.jpg` will be stored under `your_directory/a/b/abc.jpg` while `$_enableFilesDispersion = true;`  otherwise it will be stored under `your_directory/abc.jpg`